# GNU screen updating or reinstalling

Tags: terminal

Is there a way of updating GNU screen for Mac OS X 10.11.5?

My current screen version is 4.00.03 and would like to use the features such as `layout` which does not seem to be available for me.

If not, can I uninstall this version of GNU screen and install it from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/ ?

Answer (score 13):

You could install [brew](http://brew.sh) and use it to install a more recent version with the command `brew install screen`. That will currently install version 4.3.1, which (as of writing) is almost the latest release (a new release of screen came out less than a week ago and isn't in brew yet). You will then be able to run it from `/usr/local/bin/screen`. You can create an alias to simplify that.

You could remove the installed version, but it could be silently replaced by Apple at some point when you install an update. And it's always a good idea to avoid making changes in the `/usr/bin` directory unless absolutely necessary.

You could install directly from the source, but that version might not include OS X specific patches. The brew Formula for screen does include at least one specific OS X patch.

Comment: You are now, officially, my new favorite person. I could be convinced to construct a palace in your honor. The version of screen that shipped with my new Mac was one from before vertical splitting was supported, and it was driving me insane.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create an alias because homebrew will create a symlink automatically for you. Just check that that your PATH has the `/opt/homebrew/bin` folder via: `echo $PATH | grep --color /opt/homebrew/bin`. If not, use `brew doctor`.